# ERROR when trying to run Nextflow for RNAseq on MacOSX (M2)

Tags: bash, macos, nextflow, rna-seq

The error I am getting is this right when I try to download the pipeline and test it on a minimal dataset with a single command:

```
$ nextflow run nf-core/rnaseq -profile test,conda --outdir /Users/aggardik/workflow
N E X T F L O W  \~  version 0.30.1
Launching `nf-core/rnaseq` \[jovial_nightingale\] - revision: 6e1e448f53 \[master\]
ERROR \~ Unknown config attribute `params.genomes.GRCh37.projectDir` -- check config file: /Users/aggardik/anaconda3/envs/RNAseq/share/nextflow/assets/nf-core/rnaseq/nextflow.config

\-- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details
(RNAseq)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I think are needed here:

- A newer version of Nextflow which enables [DSL2](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html) be default; and
- To specify a revision when running the workflow

For example:

```
nextflow run nf-core/rnaseq \
    -profile test,conda \
    -revision 3.10.1 \
    --outdir /Users/aggardik/workflow
```

Note that release [3.10.1](https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq/tree/3.10.1) requires Nextflow >= 22.10.1<sup>[1](https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq/tree/3.10.1#quick-start)</sup>

If you installed `nextflow` using Conda, you could try using `conda update nextflow` to update Nextflow to the latest version. Otherwise, please see the [installation](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/getstarted.html#installation) documentation to get started.